# Passing a value to a file called using php exec function

Tags: php

I am using **exec** function to run my php file in background from another like below

```
<?php
$username = 'Test';
exec(PHP_BINDIR."/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/myscript/test.php >/dev/null &" );
?>
```

i want to send a value to the file which runs in background.
i tried below code

```
<?php
$username = 'Test';
exec(PHP_BINDIR."/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/myscript/test.php?user=".$username." >/dev/null &" );
?>
```

**Test.php**

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

but i got null as the value. can any one help me. how i can pass a value to a file which is running in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as command line argument:

```
$command = sprintf('%s/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/myscript/test.php %s >/dev/null &',
                   PHP_BINDIR,
                   escapeshellarg($username));

exec($command);
```

In the file:

```
$username = $argv[1];
```

You can't use URL-style query parameters because you're not using a URL, you're calling an executable.

Comment: will this `escapeshellarg()` works in all web hosting provider ?? can i send large string, array ?

Comment: `escapeshellarg` exists in all relevant PHP versions, if a host allows `exec`, it would also very much be in their interest to allow `escapeshellarg` with it. No, you cannot send arrays, only strings. I'm not sure if there's a size limit to the string length, it's probably reasonably high.